# Adding eldoc support to js2-mode

Tags: commands, js2-mode, eldoc

Since `js2-mode` does not have `eldoc-mode` support, I was wondering if I could get some similar functionality to `js2-mode` with the help of `tern-mode`.

`tern-mode` has a command `tern-get-type` which will return the type of the thing under cursor in the minibuffer. How can I get this command to run automatically when cursor is idle (preferably after a small delay)?

Comment: Not the same thing but close, have you looked at Helm Dash https://github.com/areina/helm-dash ?

Comment: I already have the `dash` app for mac for browsing documentation. Yes, I did try out `helm-dash`, but eventually decided it's better to stick with `dash` app for mac instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right thing to do is to run this `tern-get-type` from `eldoc-documentation-function`.  This way, `eldoc-mode` will take care of running it after a little delay etc...

I.e. maybe something like

```
(defun js2--eldoc-via-tern ()
  ...(tern-get-type..)...)

(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq-local eldoc-documentation-function #'js2--eldoc-via-tern)))
```

You might even do that to `js-mode` rather than `js2-mode` (since nowadays `js2-mode` inherits from `js-mode`).

If/when it works, I suggest you submit it for inclusion in js(2)-mode, e.g. via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I'll try this out today.And is it okay to report this? Since not everyone who uses `js2-mode` will use `tern-mode` and this would cause a dependancy on `tern-mode`

Comment: I don't guarantee that it will be accepted and integrated, but it's definitely worth submitting.  The various different major modes should aim to merge rather than to diverge and re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I got this to work and reported this feature as a bug. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan Please post the working solution!

Comment: @PhilHudson I use tern-mode with js2-mode now. So, it doesn't have the problem I mentioned in this old post.